# Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**This is a chrome extension**

I have a function that checks a PHP file for messages to use `chrome.notifications.create`. PHP file echo's a JSON-encoded object such as `{"status":true,"message":"test message"}`.

```
function CheckRemoteNotifications(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get("loggedInUser", function(data){
        if(data.loggedInUser){
            $.get("https://example.com/path/to/file.php", function(data){
                if(data.status){
                    try{
                        chrome.notifications.create("rds"+Math.random(1000,1000000),{
                            type: "basic",
                            iconUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL("icon-420x420.png"),
                            title: "Alert",
                            message: data.message,
                            requireInteraction: true
                        });
                    }catch(err){alert(err)};
                }
            })
        };
    });
}
```

When ran, the output shows an `Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object` error. Nothing is alert'd. This is a background page.

How do I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide more context like where did you post messages or establish connections?

Comment: @HaibaraAi The initial part of the script is just the code in the question and then a statement calling it (passing no arguments). The whole script doesn't use setPort or anything like that.

Comment: There is nothing _in this code_ that could possibly generate this error. Something is trying to use `sendMessage` or `connect`. Your console should contain a stack to see where this error occurs.

Comment: And, as an aside, thank you for bringing `requireInteraction` to my attention.

Comment: @Xan Error is here http://prntscr.com/b7n0uk

Comment: That's extension API internals; go [further up the stack](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#pause-on-exceptions).